# Is there any reason why you shouldn't perform your own algorithm to scramble IDs for security purposes?

Tags: javascript, python, sql, security, backend

I am planning to implement my own very simple "hashing" formula to add a layer of security to an app with multiple users. My current plan is as follows:

1. User creates an account at which point an ID is generated on the backend. The ID is run through a formula (let's say ID * 57 + 8926 - 36 * 7, or something equally random). I then send back to the frontend the new user ID and the new "hashed" number and store them in `localStorage`.
2. User tries to access a secured area (let's say a settings page so they can change their own settings).
3. I send the backend two values: their ID and the hashed number. I run the ID through the same formula to check it matches the hashed value I've received. If the check passes, they can get in. So if someone has tried, say, changing their ID in `localStorage` to get access to another user's settings page, the only way they could achieve that is if they guess what the formula was. They could easily guess a user ID, but guess that the corresponding number is the result of ID * 57 + 8926 - 36 * 7 seems pretty unlikely.

I'm doing this because it would be quicker/cheaper than a db lookup for an actual hashed value... I think? Would it make more sense to use a package to create some kind of primary key/uuid instead of "hashing" my own value and doing a db lookup each time?

Tech stack: React on FE, Python on BE, SQL db.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [security.se].

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll cross-post, Thanks!

Comment: For anyone following along, the Stack Exchange Info Sec thread is here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248215/is-there-any-speed-benefit-to-performing-your-own-algorithm-to-scramble-ids-for

Comment: It looks like you are trying to re-invent an authenticated session scheme. Why not just use proper session handling?

Comment: "Is there a speed benefit?" is not a security concern. That's a pure performance question. And everything in your post is about performance and not about security, threats, or protection. I'm not seeing how this is on-topic here.

Comment: And please do not cross-post on StackExchange.

Comment: Please do not cross-post on StackExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two property of real hashes that you are missing with this are

- a simple change in the input causes a large change in the output
- all hashes have the same length

This could be a problem if a user somehow knows their own id and hash.
With your selfmade hash I could easily find out the hash of a random other user by reverse engeniering the hash.

[image]

Comment: Those two properties are irrelevant here. In fact, plain MD5 would be useless here, since any attacker that can guess a valid ID can also easily compute its MD5. What is needed in this situation is unpredictability of the ID, which can be achieved by assigning users a random 128 bit uuid.

Answer (score 2):

> I see a lot of posts saying "don't roll your own" -- is this absolute?

Yes it is. The reason being that whenever a non-cryptographer tries their hand at developing their own algorithms, they invariably fall into a multitude of pit holes which render the security of the algorithm to next to useless.

Your particular scheme, for example, can be trivially broken given two consecutive ID and "hash" pairs. (It's a simple arithmetic sequence, deriving the formula of an arithmetic sequence given two consecutive values is grade ~6 level math.)

> I'm doing this because it would be quicker/cheaper than a db lookup for an actual hashed value...

The performance difference would probably be negligible. Don't worry about it.

If the information is not particularly sensitive, just assign each user a randomly generated 128 bit number. The chances of someone guessing a valid user's number are practically zero.